# python shell 3.5.2 confusion over type conversion

Tags: python, shell, type-conversion

Hi I am new to programming in general and am going through a tutorial and came to the section on type conversion and was experimenting with different scenarios. So the problem is when I use the input function such as

```
int (input("Enter a number"))
```

when I enter an integer it is fine but if I enter a float it returns the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 1, in <module>
    int(input("Enter a number:"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.2'
```

if I try the same logic and substitute int with float and enter an integer the shell returns a float just fine.I am using Python IDLE 3.5 on a windows 7 machine. Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert a string showing a floating-point number to `int` directly. This makes sense, since when the user enters a floating point number it should not "silently" be converted to the closest integer. The converse -- converting a string showing an integer to `float` -- is not as problematic, as every integer (unless it is *very* large) can equally well be represented as a floating point number.

You can, however, convert the string to `float`, and then convert that `float` to `int`:

```
>>> int(float(input("Enter a number: ")))
Enter a number: 1.2
1
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks for putting my mind at ease. I thought I had a problem with the program. Lol

Comment: @mcmjrty Glad I could help; I wasn't too sure I understood the question.